# Is any way that some method work each 1 hour in php?

Tags: php

For instance i have a function that take screenshot of `google.com` and store result at database . I want it works each 24 hour and don't know how .
I mean something cool like trigger in javascript   .
example in js:

```
function ChangeDate() {
    var changedate = ScriptApp.newTrigger('tOdAy')
      .timeBased()
      .everyDays(1)
      .create();
}
```

I have tried `sleep(time)` before in a `while(true)`loop but it didn't work.

```
function ss(){
Mycode();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this in two ways:

First one, is to create a simple script that does that, and executing it with a cron job. Plain and simple.

The other one is to create a long running script. The idea is that you create a loop, and inside that loop you call the timeout, and then execute your function. You can use [`reactphp/event-loop`](https://github.com/reactphp/event-loop) for implementing this very easily if you are using [composer](https://getcomposer.org/). Just check out the [`EventLoopInterface::addPeriodicTimer` method](https://github.com/reactphp/event-loop#addperiodictimer).

Keep in mind that you have to keep that long running process alive with some tooling like `systemd` or `supervisord`.